# NetBSD kernel - C Prog

Tags: unix, netbsd

I am trying to boot the system in silent mode by setting the `AB_SILENT` flag in the boothowto variable.

I'm new to the NetBSD kernel - can anyone throw some light on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you done that? Have you modified the boot.cfg for example by a line :

```
menu=Boot silent user:boot netbsd -z
```

where -z is the silent mode.

Welcome to NetBSD

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I ll try it out. But i am looking for editing boothowto variable value which is passed as argument from bootloader to kernal. If u have any info, it will be helpful.

Comment: which kind of netbsd do you use? 5 or current (soon 6) or an other?

Comment: I use NetBSD version 5.
Is setting boothowto variable depends on any other flag?
I mean I came across something like bootsuppress message flag?

Thanks.

Comment: kern.boothowto seems to be bringed since sysctl(7). Have a look at your /etc/sysctl.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the kern.boothowto, may be have you seen this links :
http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sysctl+7+NetBSD-currenthttp://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sysctl+7+NetBSD-current and http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?9+boothowto+NetBSD-currenthttp://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?9+boothowto+NetBSD-current.  I did not try it, but it can help you.